# Как добавить иконку по центру через css?

Tags: html, css

Есть вот такой блок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Его html выглядит так:

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger">Хром – это современный веб-обозреватель, где вы сможете быстро найти любую интересующую вас информацию. Браузер работает на высокопроизводительном движке Chromium, что позволяет опережать всех своих конкурентов на 25% по времени загрузки веб-страницы. Компания Google постоянно работает над платформой браузера и усовершенствует ее, чтобы и дальше оставаться лидером. Перед тем как скачать программу, детально ознакомьтесь с плюсами и минусами Google Chrome.</div>
```

я хочу через **alert-danger:before** сделать чтобы было так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то есть чтобы текст немного ушел вправо, а слева по центру блока была иконка.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Наверное как-то так)

```css
.alert-danger {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 65px;
}

.alert-danger:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  left: calc(-65px + 15px / 2);
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/2621/2621136.png');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger">
  Хром – это современный веб-обозреватель, где вы сможете быстро найти любую интересующую вас информацию. Браузер работает на высокопроизводительном движке Chromium, что позволяет опережать всех своих конкурентов на 25% по времени загрузки веб-страницы.
  Компания Google постоянно работает над платформой браузера и усовершенствует ее, чтобы и дальше оставаться лидером. Перед тем как скачать программу, детально ознакомьтесь с плюсами и минусами Google Chrome.
</div>
```